# Put images together in a grid with semi-transparent borders

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a list of images and I am putting them into a grid together knowing the number of rows and columns. Each image have an overlap of 32 pixels. I created an alpha channel, which makes the borders semi-transparent (32 pix) of each image.

I tried to use the Image.paste() function, but then these borders were still semi-transparent. I assumed that if you put together two images, when both of them 50% transparent you would get a non-transparent image.

Then I tried to use Image.alpha_composite(), which made it a bit better, but still not good enough.

I am lost and would be happy with any help!

```
for i, img in enumerate(image_list):
        img = Image.open(img)

#the new image is created before based on the number of rows and cols and the image size

        new_img.paste(img,box=(i % cols * (w-32), i // cols * (h-32)))

#or
        new_img.alpha_composite(img, source=(0,0), dest=(i % cols * (w-32), i // cols * (h-32))
```

These are the results I get now, but I want the borders to be kind of blended.[image: paste_function]

[image: alpha_composite_function]

Comment: 50% + 50% makes 75% - i.e. the original half plus a further half of the other half.

Comment: As it stands, your question neither shows what you have nor what you want... only what you don't want.

Comment: @MarkSetchell, yes, you are correct. I did not show what I need, but  basically the overlapping borders should not be transparent. How can I reach it? I am a bit surprised that 50% + 50% will make 75%, but it makes sense